# How do I set a text element to 0px width?

Tags: html, css

In order to make transition effects, I would like to know if it is possible to set width to 0 pixel on a HTML element that contains text. When the user will click, the element will grow.

If I do this, the text will still appear which is not what I want :

```css
div {
  width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: You just need to add "overflow:hidden" to the element for this to work.

Comment: Also you can't transition to/from `auto`.

Comment: @DanielBeck right! Couldn't be simpler and yet I didn't think of that. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The element is zero-width (as you can see by adding a border), but the text overflows the container so is still visible:

```css
div {
  width: 0px;
  border:1px solid
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

To correct this, add "overflow: hidden" to the element:

```css
div {
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I'm ashamed I didn't think of doing the trick with overflow property.

Comment: Not at all!  It's a perfectly reasonable question, this is one of the counterintuitive details of css layout that catches all of us at least once, I think

Answer (score 2):

```
div {
  width: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: it isnt, I derped my paste. fixed